# simplemodal cross domain issue

Tags: simplemodal

I am using simplemodal and js is loading from another site so both window.parent.ModalBox.close(); and window.parent.$.ModalBox.close(); not working.

I am getting this javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined"

This is working on Firefox but have issue in Chrome.

chrome also showing this error "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL"

Answer (score 0):

[The same origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy) doesn't allow accessing DOM properties and methods across different domains. You can use [postMessage API](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgheukc.php) for enabling cross-origin communication.